# Go WorkGroup doesn't synchronize functions

Tags: go, waitgroup

This is just an abstract example. `test` will work as long as it receives messages from `test2`. Then when they are all done `wg.Done()` will be called, and application will close after `wg.Wait()`.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

var a = make(chan bool)
var wg sync.WaitGroup

func main() {
    go test()
    wg.Add(1)
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        go test2()
        wg.Add(1)
    }
    wg.Wait()
}

func test() {
    defer wg.Done()
    for {
        val := <-a
        fmt.Println(val)
    }
}

func test2() {
    defer wg.Done()
    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        a <- true
    }
}
```

At least this is theory, but it doesn't translate well to practice. It correctly displays `true` 15 times, but then application crashes with a deadlock, because `wg.Done()` is never called. I'm quite stumped, because this is how it's done in tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

The goroutine created in `test` will never terminate, because of that, the wait group count will never reach zero and it will wait indefinitely.

Terminate the endless for-loop after 3 writes and the program should work, because you are reading 3 times from the channel.

Also, you have to call `wg.Add` before creating the goroutine, not after. `wg.Done` may be called before you can add to it, causing a panic.

Comment: What should I do if we assume that I don't know how many messages I will receive?

Comment: Usually, the sending end closes the channel when done, so the receiver end can range on the channel. range will receive from the channel until it closes.

Comment: I can't close the channel in test2 because I can't be sure that it was closed in the last step.

Comment: You should close it in `test`, not `test2`

Comment: So the answer is that this type of application cannot be done with golang.

Comment: No. The way you are doing is wrong. Of course it can be done with golang.

Comment: You seem to lack the basic understanding of how channels work. Work through the tour of go, and there you can see how it is done.